# Put 2 objects inside the object

Tags: php, laravel

I'm writing some queries and receiving the `$help_articles`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Creative Agency Creation",
        "sub_title": "Learn how to create creative agency and setup information and users",
        "featured_image": image.jpg",
        "content": "[{some content}]",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "Create New User",
        "sub_title": "Instruction to create new user",
        "featured_image": "56095569_step_3.jpg",
        "content": "[{some_content}]",
    }
]
```

Another query is returning $related_articles

```
[
    {
        "title": "Creative Agency Creation",
        "slug": "creative-agency-creation"
    },
    {
        "title": "Create New User",
        "slug": "create-new-user"
    },
]
```

I need 2 put this 2 objects in 1 like this:

```
{
"all_articles": [
    {
        "id": 10,
        "title": "Creative Agency Creation",
        "sub_title": "Learn how to create creative agency and setup information and users",
        "featured_image": image.jpg",
        "content": "[{some content}]",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "title": "Create New User",
        "sub_title": "Instruction to create new user",
        "featured_image": "56095569_step_3.jpg",
        "content": "[{some_content}]",
    }
],
"related_articles": [
        {
            "title": "Creative Agency Creation",
            "slug": "creative-agency-creation"
        },
        {
            "title": "Create New User",
            "slug": "create-new-user"
        },
 ]
}
```

I'm making the following:

```
 $final = new \stdClass();
        $final=$help_articles;
        $final['related_articles'] = $related_articles;

            return response()->json($final);
```

But I didn't get the required result.

Please advice, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this

Comment: You are treating an object as if it was an array - `$final['related_articles'] = ...` You can just _use_ an associative array to begin with, the JSON encoding will make it into object syntax anyway.

Comment: And of course `all_articles` won't come into existence all by itself.

Comment: To be more clear, replace `$final=$help_articles;` with `$final['all_articles']=$help_articles;` No need for the first lien, or replace it with `$final = [];`

Answer (score 1):

@Cbroe, thanks a lot, it's helped.
The solution was simple:

```
 $final = [
            'all_articles' => $help_articles,
            'related_articles' => $related_articles
        ];
            return response()->json($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `compact()`? It was like

```
$all_articles = []; //some array
$related_articles = []: //some data
return response()->json(compact(['all_articles', 'related_articles']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work in your case.

```
$final = new stdClass();

$final->all_articles =  $all_articles;
$final->related_articles =  $related_articles;

return response()->json($final);
```